# Google Assistant SDK Raspberry PI

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

im trying to get the assistant to run from my pi2 and im in the middle of getting the auth code following the steps https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/install-sample

but when i do `google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \
          --save --headless --client-secrets /path/to/client_secret_client-id.json`

i get back

```
-bash: google-oauthlib-tool: command not found
```

any ideas?

Comment: Have you run `pip install google-oauthlib-tool` in a virtual Python environment?

Comment: when i run that command which i thought i had already as i was following the google walk through this is what i get

`$ pip install google-oauthlib-tool
Collecting google-oauthlib-tool
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-oauthlib-tool (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for google-oauthlib-tool
`

Comment: Did you first run `python3 -m venv env` and `source env/bin/activate`

Comment: ok i tried what you suggested and this is what gets returned

`
pip install google-oauthlib-tool
Collecting google-oauthlib-tool
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-oauthlib-tool (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for google-oauthlib-tool
`

Comment: Can you try running going through this step on your phone and, after generating the credentials, ssh the file to your Pi?